# How can I call an instance of a singleton class based on a properties file in java?

Tags: java, properties, junit, singleton, instance

I have a quick Java question. Oh and I'm fairly new to both Java and stackoverflow, so please be considerate :)

Let me try to explain my question a little better. So I have two classes that follow a singleton pattern, say class A and class B:

```
public class A
{
    private static final A INSTANCE = new A()

    public static A getInstance()
    {
         return A.INSTANCE;
    }
}

public class B
{
    private static final B INSTANCE = new B()

    public static B getInstance()
    {
         return B.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now I'm accessing instances of these classes from another class, let's say C:

```
public class testClassC
{
    A class_instance = A.getInstance();
    //or
    //B class_instance = B.getInstance();
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this (the syntax might be totally wrong at this point, I've been trying different things and none of them worked for me):

Have a .properties file as follows:

```
 className=A
```

And then somehow read the class name from that properties file so that when I change A to B, my testClassC will get me an instance of B.

How can I achieve this? Oh and again testClassC is a test class and I have a whole bunch of those JUnit test classes so what would be the best way to approach this?

Thank you

Comment: How flexible do you want it to be? If you don't care too much about making it flexible, you can just create a Map<String, Object> that stores the name of the class along with the singleton for that class.

Comment: @RobWatts Where would I store that Map object though? Basically what I have is 3 types of storage classes: RAM, XML and SQL. And then I have test class that tests my storage. What I want to be able to do is have a properties file where I can just change my class name to RAM and my test class will create an instance of RAM storage class, and test that.

Comment: You should read up on Dependency Injection because that's exactly what you are looking for. Here's an [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html) covering Spring DI. You should carefully read it and especially chapter 6.

Comment: I think Spring is probably overkill. I would go for [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) - it's a little less heavyweight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using an abstract factory pattern.

You have an `interface` which defines your class - you need this so that you can abstract the actual implementation.

You then have a factory interface which defines the `newInstance` method. This makes it very easy to swap a singleton pattern for a factory pattern. It also makes it easy it easy to change the factory implementation for testing.

```
interface MyInterface {
}

interface MyInterfaceFactory {

    MyInterface newInstance();
}

class MyInterfaceFactoryFromProperties implements MyInterfaceFactory {

    final Class<? extends MyInterface> myInterfaceImpl;

    {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(MyInterfaceFactoryFromProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("className.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        final String className = properties.getProperty("class.name");
        try {
            myInterfaceImpl = (Class<? extends MyInterface>) MyInterfaceFactoryFromProperties.class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyInterface newInstance() {
        try {
            return myInterfaceImpl.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So your factory implementation would follow this pattern but you could, for example, cache the value to make it a singleton.

This method loads the properties file from the classpath - obviously this can be changed to a filesystem location.

Comment: Thanks to all the other responders as well, and yes, I will read up on dependency injection. We covered it briefly in our crash course but it was never really stressed. I guess I'll find out what it does pretty soon.